# Div extends beyond wrapper div

Tags: html

I have a div inside a wrapper div. I noticed that it (the inner div) extends beyond the wrapper div. I'm using IE8. Here's the code:

```
#div_wrapper_slideshow {

position:absolute;
height: 275px;
width: 100%;
display: block;

}

#div_slideshow {

position:relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background:#123456;

}


<div id="div_wrapper_slideshow"> 
      <div id="div_slideshow">

      </div> <!-- end of div id="div_slideshow" --> 

</div> <!-- end of div id="div_wrapper_slideshow" -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You give your wrapper div a fixed height - 275px. So if the inside div gets too big it flows out and over. You can use the `overflow` [css parameter](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp) for other behaviors.